# Mojo Dependency issue with java 1.7

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, java-7

**Background**: I have a EJB application which runs on java 1.7 and we are using maven 3+ version for building the code.

**Issue**: When I build this code I am getting java version mismatch issue i.e major and minor issue.

**Error**:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.0:install (default-install) on project XYZ: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.0:install failed: Unable to load the mojo 'install' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/apache/maven/plugins/install/InstallMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/3.1.0/maven-install-plugin-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/A/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.3.0/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.test:XYZ:9.0.5-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
```

Java Version : 1.7
Maven Version : 3.8.6

FYI: I don't want to change the java version

**Things I have already checked:**

1. Cleared .m2 folders and build.
2. Checked java version it's pointing to 1.7
3. Checked java compilation version and it's pointing to 1.7
4. Checked the maven version and it's java version which it is pointing to and the version is 1.7

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Instead of just **deleting** the image, you should post the error message as code-formatted text in its place.

Comment: I suggest to use a more recent JDK (for example JDK17) and configuration via `<maven.compiler.release>7</maven.compiler.release` to generate class files for JDK7.... much easier than using such ancient tools and JDk version ...

Answer (score 1):

`maven-install-plugin` 3.1.0 [requires Java 8](https://github.com/apache/maven-install-plugin/releases/tag/maven-install-plugin-3.1.0). You need to switch to an earlier version, like 3.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, the build is success after adding this dependency. But previously this was working fine without adding the maven-install-plugin. dependency.

Comment: @sangeeta: maybe some other plugin change introduced a dependency to the new version?

Comment: If that has worked before that means the plugins haven't be fixed by using the pluginManagement which is strongly recommend to get reproducible builds...